# How can I determine if an angular factory/service has been previously injected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I have an angular factory that performs some tasks upon injection into other objects.   In some cases, I inject the factory using $injector.get() and in other cases, it is injected through the function declaration of the controller, service, etc.

I would like to determine if the factory has previously been injected.  I could implement a Boolean value on the angular module and then trip the flag during factory initialization, but that seems clunky.

Is there a list of objects that have been previously injected during the life-cycle of an angular module?

Thoughts?

Comment: Angular doesn't inject a factory. Angular injects a service instance created by the factory function. So, I don't understand what you mean by "perform task upon injection". Can you give an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm curious. What would be the application of this knowledge? In other words, why do you need to know?

Comment: @Brett, are you referring to why an example is needed? To prevent things like XY questions. To better understand this question. For example, the factory function runs when it is being injected and it runs only once. The most trivial thing to do would be to set a variable there.

Comment: @NewDev I understand the implementation and that it is instantiated only once in memory. I don't need an example. What I don't understand is why he would care whether it's been instantiated already. What's the purpose? Basically, my question relates to yours. He probably doesn't mean "factory".

Comment: @Brett, ah, nevermind... I thought you meant why *I* needed to know. Yes, an example is important - that was my comment as well.

Comment: @New Dev...correct, the most trivial thing to do would be set a variable during the instance creation.   I'm asking if there's something in angular that already tells me that the instance has been created.  Brett, to answer your question...I have several objects that are created/injected when needed throughout the application.   Those objects pull data from the server during initialization.   I want to respond to a user action to refresh all initialized objects.   So, I'm trying to determine which objects have been initialized.

Comment: @GregGrater, what does it mean to "refresh"? You *may* be approaching this from a wrong angle. Do you have cached data that you need to refresh? Then create a common caching service that all other services depend on, or have a common service that tracks "freshness" and use that everywhere you need.

Comment: @GregGrater Hmm, it might be a better implementation to separate the responsibility of those data pulls into a singleton (i.e. an Angular service) and have those objects depend on the service.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.   Maybe a better way to ask this question is...how do I remove the singleton from the providerCache so that the next time it is injected, a new singleton is instantiated?   Think of a logout situation where I want to remove the singleton services that contain data collected during the lifetime of the application.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the [$injector service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector).
Although you can't specifically see if it has been injected and is currently in use, you can see if the service exists using:

```
$injector.has('serviceName')
```

Comment: The fact that angular knows about a factory/service doesn't help with knowing if an instance has already been created.  I've tested $injector.has and it always returns true regardless if the factory/service has been instantiated.

Comment: rats... i was hoping that was the behavior of `injector.has`, but no, @GregGrater is correct.